# Vim Autocorrect when wrong spelling is typed

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How do you make vim auto correct a spelling by replacing it with the first suggestion  automatically immediately after I finish typing that word? 
I tried

`:imap <Space> <Space><ESC>h1z=<End>I<End>`

But this replaces all the correct words with the wrong ones.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think auto-correcting is a good idea (how do you deal with words Vim doesn't know yet?), but I have this insert mode mapping to quickly correct the last misspelled word. Just press `<C-Z>` when the red squiggly lines appear while typing:

```
:inoremap <C-z> <Esc>[s1z=gi
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make the suggestions show that word as first suggestion if it is right?
Or is there a way to check if the word under the cursor currently has the right spelling?

Comment: You can check with `spellbadword()`, but I don't think you can influence the suggestion list itself. You'd have to implement something yourself with `spellsuggest()`.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider https://github.com/panozzaj/vim-autocorrect for a method that tries to auto correct many Vim typos right after you type them.